# How to use chained page object locators?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I have a function, contains the page objects

```
class TemplateListPage:
   def __init__(self, page):
      self.list_first_row = self.page.locator(".grid-row").first
      self.use_btn = self.page.locator(".useTemplate")
```

And I would like to chain the button with the first row in assertion, in the spec test.
Like

```
expect(TemplateListPage().list_first_row.use_btn).to_have_count(0)
```

or

```
TemplateListPage().list_first_row.use_btn.click()
```

But got an error:

> AttributeError: 'Locator' object has no attribute 'use_btn'

Is there any way that I can chain the page object locators in the test?

Comment: The way you have it set up, this isn't really possible since `self.page.locator(".useTemplate")` is already locating directly on the whole `page`, not on `page.locator(".grid-row").first` specifically. You can't re-chain that assignment after the fact. Sure, you could use some introspection to make this possible but, eh, I'd suggest just writing normal, readable Python code instead of trying to be too clever.

Comment: I think, this is a standard way to build class for different pages and collect the page objects for the page. With this, you will have to adapt here only if anything changed for an element.

Comment: as @ggorlen mentioned, you are addressing your button to the hole page. you can inject a locator to a locator ```locator(page.locator())``` or you can ```.filter()``` your locators. nevertheless, you can chain locators, because ```first``` returns a locator. However you could  chain  like ```first_row = ....locator("...").first```  -> ```btn = locator(....)``` --> ```first_row.locator(btn)```

Comment: `TemplateListPage().list_first_row.use_btn` isn't standard. There's no easy way to do that with locators. `TemplateListPage().list_first_row_use_btn` is much easier and more standard, but then the relationship is hardcoded. With only 2 locators, there's no way to determine whether this makes sense in your larger use case (I assume you want to reuse `.use_btn` on many different parent locators).

Comment: Thank you, @KlimBom unfortunately, I cannot use btn = locator(....) because page is needed (got error "Unresolved reference 'locator'" anyway).
Yes, ggorlen, I would like to use the POs for all rows. The table rows could change dynamically, so there is a use_btn for all rows... When writing the script, I would use the nth as for loop param for rows and pick the related use_btn of that specific row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playwright recently added the [and_](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-locator#locator-and) locator, which should allow you to achieve what your aiming for:

```py
expect(TemplateListPage().use_btn.and_(TemplateListPage().list_first_row)).to_have_count(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't know about the existance of the **and_** locator. Why didn't the Playwright team called it **and** instead of **and_** ?

Comment: Yes, this feature is available from v1.34, so I need to upgrade :)
https://playwright.dev/python/docs/release-notes#version-134

Comment: @hpr `and` is a keyword so `and_` needs to be used.